# Why is my world not unlimited?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Strangely I can see all my world with its very limited resouces. I can't get past the edge. I bought it only last night (23/4/15) so isn't it supposed to be unlimited? It's mostly water with some various biome islands... spruce trees on most, one with oak & beech. How can I play in such a tiny world? I've made about 5 different worlds, & all are like that, some more watery than others. All small in area. A couple of sheep, maybe a cow, no chickens or pigs so far. Does it improve with time?

Answer (score 3):

Since version 0.9.0, Minecraft: Pocket Edition allows infinite worlds, but classic 256 by 256 worlds are still supported as a separate world type.

While creating a world, look for an **Advanced** button, and select **Infinite** world type in Advanced options.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of minecraft you can edit your worlds and make them infinite.

Just press the edit button next to the world, and Press the "make infinite" button.

Comment: Is there such a button?

Comment: Yes in version 11.1, when you edit a world, there should be such a button

Comment: Ok then. Need to update minecraft soon.